# Facebook login works fine on web-app version of my app but not the installed PWA version

Tags: progressive-web-apps, facebook-login

When hitting the Facebook login button in my web-app it takes me to a Facebook page with a "Continue as Shaun" button, and when I hit it it successfully logs me into my web-app (without having to enter my Facebook email and password).

Doing the same in the installed PWA of my app instead opens up a login form forcing the user to enter their Facebook email and password.

What is the correct method that I should be learning to instead have the PWA open the page with the "Continue as..." button please?